# in wicket, how could you add custom attribute to an option in Select component?

Tags: java, wicket

The goal is to reproduce the following with wicket:

```
<select wicketid="mySelect">
  <option data-img="123">test1</option>
</select>
```

Problem is that I dont know how many options will be there, so options must be made dynamically.

I tried dropdownchoice with passing a list to it. it generates the options correctly but I have no way of inserting the data-img attributes in them. The ChoiceRenderer only works for id and value.

I also tried using AttributeAppender, but for that I need to know the exact number of options and each must have a predefined wicketid.

Any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can override org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.AbstractChoice#setOptionAttributes().
Or you can use org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.select.Select with org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.select.SelectOption.